# Como recibir en php el resultado de mi variable de localstorage

Tags: php

Hola a todos y gracias por su apoyo, tengo un botón donde tiene asignado una arreglo para almacenar productos, el código de este en js es el siguiente:

```
    var agr = document.getElementById("agregar");
    agr.addEventListener("click", Agregar);
    document.getElementById("agregar").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    });
    function Agregar() {
        var accesorio = document.getElementById("accesorios");
        var pieza = document.getElementById("piezas");
        //const pieza=document.querySelector('#piezas');
        carrito.push(accesorio.value);
        carrito.push(pieza.value);
        console.log(carrito);
        // convertimos el array en un json para enviarlo al PHP
        //var arrayJson=JSON.stringify(carrito);
       
       // console.log(arrayJson);
        //localStorage.setItem(arrayJson, 'Juan');
        //localStorage.clear();
    }
```

ahora cuando quiero enviar esta información al servidor uso este código , el cual esta asignado a otro boton:

```
    var coti = document.getElementById("cotizar");
    coti.addEventListener("click", Cotizar);
    document.getElementById("cotizar").addEventListener("click", function(event){
        event.preventDefault()
    });
    function Cotizar() {
        //localStorage.clear();
        var con =localStorage.setItem('arrayJson', JSON.stringify(carrito));
        var saved = parseInt(con);
        console.log(localStorage);
    // var con = localStorage.getItem(carrito);
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ejemplophp.php",
            data: { data: saved },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
                //$('#output').html(data);
                alert(data.mensaje);
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
                console.log(error);
            }
        });  
    }
```

El problema que tengo es que no se como leerlo en php, tengo este código:

```
    $resultado = array('mensaje' => '');
        if( isset($_POST['data']) ) {
            $resultado['mensaje'] = "Viene el valor : ".$_POST['data'];
            echo json_decode($resultado);
            exit;
        }
```

y mi html esta de esta forma:

```
    <div class="listaCategoria">
                    <a href="catalogo.php" class="categoriaBoton " category="todos">REGRESAR</a>
                    <input class="formulario__campo" type="text"  id="accesorios">
                    <input class="formulario__campo" type="number" placeholder="Cantidad"  id="piezas" name="num_piezas">
                    <input class="formulario__submit" type="submit" id="agregar" placeholder="Agregar" value="Agregar">
                    <form action="ejemplophp.php?<?php echo "w1=$w1 w2=$w2"?>" method="GET">
                    <input class="formulario__submit" type="submit" id="cotizar" placeholder="Agregar" value="Cotizar"> 
                    </form>
```

Podrían apoyarme

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! web.. es muy grande como para que alguien te ayude con esa etiqueta... probaste ver que viene en data?

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate que en la función `Cotizar` le estás asignando a `con` el resultado de `localstorage.setItem` que por [definición](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem#return_value) es `undefined`. Entonces `saved` te queda `NaN` y el objeto que le pasas al servidor en el pedido POST es `{data: null}`.

Finalmente en tu código PHP la función `isset` por [definición](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php) retorna `false` cuando la variable es `null`. Por eso nunca corre el `echo`.

No te puedo ofrecer una solución porque no sé qué valor le querías pasar al servidor.

Comment: le quiero pasar un arreglo con el nombre de algun accesorio y su cantidad de accesorio por ejemplo Array(4) [ "Calibration Filter", "2", "Carry Case", "2" ]
sc, este array tiene el nombre de dos accesorios con su respectiva cantidad

Comment: @RobertoCarlosMedranomorales y eso ya lo tienes en la variable `carrito`? De ser así solo tienes que usar `data: {data: carrito}`